# Setting web part title from resource file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am trying to set web part the title and description through a resource file.
My `.webpart` file has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="MyWebParts.MyWebPart" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this web part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">$Resources:MyWebPartResources,WebPartTitle</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">$Resources:MyWebPartResources,WebPartDescr</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

I have put the resource file in `12\Resources` folder.

But, the **Add Web Part** dialogue does not seem to be picking the title and description from the resource file.

Have anyone fixed this?

**Update-1:**
On **Add Web Part** dialogue, I see the following instead of the text in resource file:

```
$Resources:MyWebPartResources,WebPartTitle
$Resources:MyWebPartResources,WebPartDescr
```

Comment: What the name of your .resx files? What language is your installation running?

Did you read this?
http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2008/02/25/sharepoint-internals-resources/

Comment: File name is MyWebPartResources.resx. I will have a look at that link.
Thanks!

Comment: According to that link, I should place the resource file in either, 
1. <hive>\12\CONFIG\Resources
2. C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<port>\App_GlobalResources\

Both the places are not working.

Way of referring resource entry is also correct:
`$Resources:MyWebPartResources,WebPartTitle`

Any comments on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link, [SharePoint Internals: Resources](http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2008/02/25/sharepoint-internals-resources/) (given by, [anchorpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78909/anchorpoint) in the comment) helped a lot. 
[Lee Dale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74715/lee-dale) is also correct. Though, Still it didn't work on my machine for the first time even though I was correct. It may be because of some caching issue.

Later, I tried clearing temporary internet files, deactivating and activating the feature, it worked!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. I should've put it as an answer instead of a comment ;)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks!
But, the entries which I had put were also correct. But, the problem was with caching. Then, clearing the temporary internet files, deactivating and activating the feature did the work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The resource file needs to be in websiteroot/App_GlobalResources I think.

The contents of 12/Resources folder only gets copied to App_GlobalResources when the web application is first created.

Comment: putting resx file in websiteroot/App_GlobalResources is also not working.

Thanks!